# Django Forms cleaned_data missing certain fields

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a strange problem with a form I have created for user registration using a Django customer user model. I'm running Django 1.6.5.

forms.py

```
class SignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,
                                label=_('Password'),
                                max_length=50)
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,
                                label=_('Repeat password'),
                                max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        model = RegisteredUser
        fields = ("firstname", "lastname", "email", "password1", "password2",)

    def clean_email(self):
        existing = RegisteredUser.objects.filter(email__iexact=self.cleaned_data['email'])
        if existing.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError(_('A user with that email already exists.'))
        return self.cleaned_data['email']

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(SignupForm, self).clean()
        if 'password1' in self.cleaned_data and 'password2' in self.cleaned_data:
            if self.cleaned_data['password1'] != self.cleaned_data['password2']:
                raise forms.ValidationError(_('The two passwords did not match.'))
        return cleaned_data
```

views.py

```
class SignUpView(FormView):
    template_name = 'core/signup.html'
    form_class = SignupForm
    success_url = None

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.get_form(self.get_form_class())
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(request, form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, request, form):
        new_user = self.register(request, **form.cleaned_data)
        success_url = self.get_success_url(request, new_user)

        try:
            to, args, kwargs = success_url
            return redirect(to, *args, **kwargs)
        except ValueError:
            return redirect(success_url)



    def register(self, request, **cleaned_data):
        RegisteredUser.objects.create_user(email=cleaned_data['username'],
                                           firstname=cleaned_data['firstname'],
                                           lastname=cleaned_data['lastname'],
                                           password=cleaned_data['password2'])
```

The form returns invalid saying that 'password1' and 'password2' are required fields. The value is clearly present in the post data along with the other fields.

No matter what I have tried, 'password1' and 'password2' are not included in the cleaned_data dict. I have tried using various other names for these two fields, just to make sure 'password2' wasn't conflicting anything else.

I'm probably overlooking something extremely simple :-)

Thanks!

Mike

EDIT 1 - the template in use (sorry for the div-hell!):

```
<section class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <h2>Create an <strong>Account</strong></h2>
                <form class="white-row" method="post" action="#">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                <label>Firstname</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                <label>Lastname</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                <label>Email</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <label>Password</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="passsword1">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <label>Repeat password</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="passsword2">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                            <input type="submit" value="Sign up" class="btn btn-primary pull-right push-bottom" data-loading-text="Loading...">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

Comment: Could you show your template ? Where you're using the form, because it's complaining that you're not filling the form well, and you do that in the template

Comment: I have updated ith the template. The error I am getting is that password1 and password2 are required. Both fields are field out and are (as mentioned) present in the post data in the request object.

Comment: I think you have a missunderstanding on django forms, where are you using `{{form}}` variable ? where are you calling `{{form.password1}}` and `{{form.password2}}` ? You are using standar inputs, html inputs `<input ....` but when you use a Django form, you have to send the form to the template, and call the fields like `{{form.password1}}`, Django will translate that to an input. Look my answer, how I'm calling the fields in the template

Comment: You were completely right. I was sure as long as i "mimiced" the names of the form fields it would work. Using {{ form.password1 }}, etc., solved the problem for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is an example of how I do this in my projects:

forms.py:

```
class NewUserForm(forms.Form):
    username = ...
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, required=True)
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, required=True)

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1", "")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2", "")
        if password1 and password2:  # If both passwords has value
            if password1 != password2:
                raise forms.ValidationError(_(u"Passwords didn't match."))
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_(u"Passwords can't be blank."))
        return password2
```

views.py:

```
@login_required
def add_user(request):
    ''' Adds new user '''

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            # TODO: Save in temporary table
            return HttpResponse('SUBMIT')
    else:
        form = NewUserForm()

    return render_to_response('add_user.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

template (form example):

```
<form action="." method="post" id="add_user_form">
{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.username }}
    {{ form.password1 }}
    {{ form.password2 }}
    {{ form.usertype }}

    <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save' %}" class="default"/>

</form>
```

`{% csrf_token %}` : You need to put this in every form you use

`action="."` : This make the post to the actual page

`{{ form.VARIABLE_NAME}}` You need to set the inputs of the form like this, you create the form in the view, send to the template, and use it as a Django variable using `{{ }}`. To set an input for one of your fields, like `password1` it will be like I wrote above `{{ form.password1}}`, you can also use `{{form.errors}}` to check all form errors, or `{{form.VARIABLE_NAME.errors}}` to check for exact field errors in the template